# Prove the following limit (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}(az+b)=az_0+b$

I am not so sure how to approach this.

$|az+b-(az_0+b)|=|az-az_0|=|a||z-z_0|\geq|z-z_0|\geq|z|$, so maybe if set $|z|\leq \epsilon$, the expression still holds. I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$ we have to show there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|z-z_0|<\delta\implies|f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon.$$
You have shown that 
$$|f(z)-f(z_0)|=|az+b-(az_0+b)|=|az-az_0|=|a||z-z_0|$$
Suppose $a$ is nonzero. Note that $|f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0|<\epsilon/|a|$. Hence choose $\delta=\epsilon/|a|$. If $a=0$ we can choose any $\delta>0$ we want (why?).

Comment: Why is $|f(z)-f(z_0)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0 |< \epsilon/|a|$?

Comment: If $|z-z_0|<\epsilon/|a|$ then $ |a||z-z_0|<|a|(\epsilon/|a|)=\epsilon$

Comment: so for your first question, because $\epsilon/|a|$ is undefined

Comment: If $a=0$, then $|f(z)-f(z_0|=|b-b|=0<\epsilon$ regardless of what $\delta$ we choose.

Answer (score 1):

choose $\delta =\min\left\{ 1,\frac { \epsilon  }{ \left| a \right|  }  \right\} $ where $a\neq 0$ so that ,$$\left| z-z_{ 0 } \right| <\delta =\min\left\{ 1,\frac { \epsilon  }{ \left| a \right|  }  \right\} \\ \left| az+b-\left( az_{ 0 }+b \right)  \right| =\left| az-az_{ 0 } \right| =\left| a \right| \left| z-z_{ 0 } \right| <\epsilon \\ \\ $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $a=0$, it's very easy; if $a\ne0$, set $\delta=\varepsilon/|a|$.